# Qt creator - using a custom x86 compiler?

Tags: qt-creator

I'm using a x86 toolchain to build the binary in Qt Creator 3.4.0 (opensource) . There is a `/usr/bin/gcc` and a `<path-to-toolchain>/i686-atom-linux-gnu-gcc` and I want to use `i686-atom-linux-gnu-gcc`.

The `Compiler path` in `Build&Run->Compilers->Compiler path` correctly set to point to `i686-atom-linux-gnu-gcc`.

When I try to observe what commands from the Makefile are being executed, it always shows that the compiler is `gcc`, while it should have a compiler prefix (`i686-atom-linux-gnu-gcc`).

Update:

The qmake call is called with a parameter `-spec linux-g++`. However, on the working version, this value corresponds to `mkspec` in `Build&Run->Qt versions->Details`.

The correct `kit` is selected in the project options. Am I missunderstanding something or could it be a bug in Qt Creator?

Comment: How many compilers have you configured in the "Compilers" list? Is it only one? Did you check the compiler that is assigned to your kit?

Comment: @SimonWarta There are 3 compilers. One is Auto-detected and other two are manual ones. In the kit settings the correct manual one is selected, however the automatic one is being used.

Comment: Did you 'run qmake' after changing the compiler or entirely remove the build directory? The Makefile needs to be re-created to apply the compiler change.

Comment: @SimonWarta Yes. And the `CC  = gcc` and `CXX = g++` in the Makefile are set without the prefix.

Comment: Might be a bug, I don't know. Try adding `"QMAKE_CXX=/<path-to-toolchain>/i686-atom-linux-gnu-gcc"` as a qmake argument in your project settings for both the release and the debug setting

Comment: That sets the `CXX` to the absolute path for the second compiler, however, the other toolchain dependet commands (`CC` and `STRIP`) remain unchanged.

Comment: There is `QMAKE_CC` as well as `QMAKE_STRIP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was doe to the wrong default `-spec linux-g++` parameter. Doe to it the generated Makefiles had the default PC toolchain instead of the one selected in the Kit.

After manually adding `-spec qws/linux-ptx-g++` in `Projects->Additional arguments:`, the generated makefile uses the correct compiler.

I got the parameter `qws/linux-ptx-g++` from `Options->Build&Run->Qt Versions->"your Qt version"->Details->mkspec`

This is a trial and error discovered answer, I'll gladly accept another that could explain this behaviour.